# Are 'tirer parti de' and 'profiter de' interchangeable?

Tags: choix-de-mot

It seems that way to me, but I wonder if they are nuanced differently.  Is one more appropriate than the other in certain contexts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say "tirer parti de" seems more neutral (or has a connotation of opportunism), when "profiter de" has a connotation of exploitation.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you.